# How to Save Navigation property in ASP.NET MVC3 using Code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

i have been using code first technique in ASP.NET MVC3 app. here it is very basic issue i.e. how to update a navigation property. following is detailed code.

```
    public class Destination
    {
        public int ID {get;set;}
       // some other properties
        public Country {get;set;}
    }

    public class Country
    {
     int ID {get;set;}
     string Name {get;set;}
    }

    //i have simple structure as above. when i go to update destination entity. Country is not getting updated.even i tried following:

    _db.Entry(Destination.Country).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    _db.Entry(Destination).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    //_db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    _db.SaveChanges();
```

Secondly when i go for Add it works fine. is there any need to have foriegnKey relationship explicityly required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add entity in three ways:

Calling the `Add()` method on DbSet. This puts the entity into the Added state, meaning that it will be inserted into the database the next time that `SaveChanges()` is called.

```
context.Destination.Add(yourDestination);
```

Changing its state to Added.

```
context.Entry(yourDestination).State = EntityState.Added;
```

Adding a new entity to the context by hooking it up to another entity that is already being tracked

```
context.Destination.Country.Add(yourCountry);
```

Regards.